# Converting string to UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf, type-conversion, uielement, dynamic-data-display

Is there a way to convert string to UIElement? I'm trying to add text to my graph's legend using an Interactive data display. The legend needs to not correlate with a plotted graph so I'm making my own like so:

```
LegendItemsPanel legendItemsPanel = new LegendItemsPanel() 
{
            
};
Legend legend = new Legend() 
{
   Content = legendItemsPanel
};
Rectangle rectUP = new Rectangle()
{
   Width = 10,
   Height = 10,
   Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
   Stroke = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Red),
};
UIElement element() 
{
   UIElement output = new UIElement();
   output.Equals(rectUP + " Upstream band");
   return output;
}
legendItemsPanel.Children.Add(element());
```

I've tried a lot of possibilities but every time I get the same error "Cannot convert from 'string' to 'Windows.System.UIElement'". Could someone please help me out with this one? Thank you

Comment: What is this line supposed to do: `output.Equals(rectUP + " Upstream band")`?

Comment: I'm trying to bind rectangle and string together somehow. So i wanted to bind them into element()

Comment: Creating a plain UIElement makes no sense. You probably want to create a more derived element, e.g. a TextBlock, and set its Text property.

Comment: You can't add a string to a Rectangle, and Equals is not an assignment operator. See what @Clemens said.

Comment: Yes, it was what i was looking for. Thank you @Clemens! May i ask one following question? How do i bind that textbox and rectangle so i can add them both as one?

Comment: Put them into a common container element, i.e. a Panel. StackPanel would be the most simple one. Please also consider reading some introductory material, e.g. a book or online tutorial about the basics of WPF.